# Pandas creating a seperate DF based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks like this:

```
                       kW   OAT  month hour  Day_of_week
Date                                                    
2018-02-18 10:45:00  44.0  63.9      2   10            6
2018-02-18 10:50:00  48.0  63.8      2   10            6
2018-02-18 10:55:00  48.0  63.8      2   10            6
2018-02-18 11:00:00  48.0  63.5      2   11            6
2018-02-18 11:05:00  54.0  63.2      2   11            6
```

How can I create an additional pandas dataframe named `summer` based on if the `month` column == 6,7,8, or 9?

This attempt throws a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

`df['summer'] = [1 if 'month' == 6 else 0]`

I was hoping for something simple like:
`df['summer'] = [1 if 'month' == 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 else 0]`

Am I at all on the right path! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a separate dataframe 'summer', you could try the below piece of code -

```
summer = df[df['month'].isin([6,7,8,9])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you want a add a column called 'summer' in the existing dataframe 'df', you could try the following -

```
import numpy as np  
df['summer'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([6,7,8,9]), 1, 0)
```